# Getting an error on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm making a website using wordpress and a custom theme. I tested the website on my computer using XAMP and it worked perfectly. But when I uploaded my code to the web hosting, it gave this error:

```
ERROR : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/a5709387/public_html/wp-content/themes/gameaddict/themeOptions/functions.php on line 1
```

Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) )
{
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Options Framework Theme
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Set the file path based on whether the Options Framework Theme is a parent theme or child theme */

        define('OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_URL', get_template_directory() . '/themeOptions/admin/');
        define('OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_template_directory_uri() . '/themeOptions/admin/');

require_once (OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_URL . 'options-framework.php');
}
/*
 * This is an example of how to add custom scripts to the options panel.
 * This one shows/hides the an option when a checkbox is clicked.
 */
add_action('optionsframework_custom_scripts', 'optionsframework_custom_scripts');
function optionsframework_custom_scripts() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#example_showhidden').click(function() {
                jQuery('#section-example_text_hidden').fadeToggle(400);
        });
        if (jQuery('#example_showhidden:checked').val() !== undefined) {
                jQuery('#section-example_text_hidden').show();
        }
});
</script>
<?php
}
/*
 * Turns off the default options panel from Twenty Eleven
 */
add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_twentyeleven_options', 100);
function remove_twentyeleven_options() {
        remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'twentyeleven_theme_options_add_page' );
}
?>
```

Comment: your code does not have { in first line

possibilities:

1. you did not provided code of themes/gameaddict/themeOptions/functions.php  here but some another file

2. your hosting aytomatically adds some code to some files (do you really want to use free hosting? they live because of serving ads or stealing data). download your file from server and check if it is the same or changed

Comment: It's just for testing, I will buy the host once the website is complete!
PS Yea somehow the script get changed, I mean all the lines get transferred to first line (but semi colon and other operators are still there)! Is that a problem?

Comment: i think it is if you have an error :)

Comment: nvm, the problem was with filezilla altering the script. I had to change from ASCII to binary and it got fixed :)